# VB.net Video Streaming Via UDP Port Error

Tags: vb.net, sockets, video, udp, udpclient

Good Day to all

I am Currently developing a video chat application with Vb.NET
I used the example as explained in this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OQcbTnykwo). The application runs, but only up to the point I can see my own Webcam but I can't connect to the client unit.

I used try, and an exception came out saying ("**The Operation is Not Allowed on Non Connected Sockets**") I traced the problem to this code:

```
Publisher.Send(sendBytes, Bitmapz)
```

I tried the following

1. Disabling my firewall
2. selecting a different port

I set the port to the one in the video btw, (2013)

What should I do to get past the error?

Comment: is both the send and receive set to the same ports?

Comment: yes. initially the sent is set to port 2013, whereas the update button sets the name of the target and port to 2013 as well.

Comment: @bensonsearch yes. Basically, I followed what's on the video, but when I ried the code it didn't work. And that error occurred. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

OK i have actually seen this before, remove the blocking lines of code and try again. eg
the listener.blocking = false, just remove it